# natbib error only when using "round" option

Tags: bibtex

When I use `sort&compress`, everything works fine:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
% ...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}
```

I get the following error *only* when I include `round` in my natbib options:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,round]{natbib}
% ...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}
```

> natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Does anyone know why this is? I've tried cleaning out temporary files and making from scratch.

Comment: Well, quite apart from the error you should be using `unsrtnat` here (or another `natbib` style).

Comment: Thanks-- unfortunately, doesn't change the error. Isn't it strange?

Comment: minimal complete example please (including bib file that you can add on top using `filecontents` environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to specify that the in-text citations should be numeric. I had (incorrectly) assumed that this would be default for `sort&compress`:

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,round]{natbib}
```